# get/input code from react codemirror2 library in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get and input the text from element when element is build by react-codemirror2 library in python selenium? I have tried

```
    el = driver.find_elements('//div[@class="CodeMirror-lines" and @role="presentation"]//pre[@class=" CodeMirror-line " and @role="presentation"]')
    text = ''.join(str(i.text) for i in el)
```

my html page is like https://scniro.github.io/react-codemirror2/
but I can only get parital of text that is visiable. not all of them.

Comment: There are no invisible elements that match that locator on the page you provided. Are there supposed to be? Selenium only interacts with visible elements on the page. It's a design decision. You can use JavascriptExecutor to get the text on hidden elements, if needed. At least on the page you provided, you can significantly simplify your locator by using a CSS selector `"pre.CodeMirror-line"`. Maybe the extra stuff was needed on your page?

Comment: from my link the code is only 25 lines but on my page it always more than 100 lines..so lots of invisible elements unless i scroll it

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but it still does not work. my issue is whenever i scroll the same xpath like **//div[@class="CodeMirror-lines" and @role="presentation"]//pre[@class=" CodeMirror-line " and @role="presentation"]'** or css **"pre.CodeMirror-line** return different number of elements